# Can't Create Session

Tags: development, authentication, security, security-token-service

I am trying to update a custom authentication page from SharePoint 2010 to 2013. It basically takes credentials from a CAC card and creates them a user account in FBA if they didn't already have one giving them visitor rights. It then creates a Security Token and establishes a session in the browser with that token.

All of this worked fine in 2010, but I have been stuck on this last piece trying to upgrade for 2013. I can create SPFederationAuthenticationModule object called fam, but whenever I try to use it I get an error asking for the base class for SPFederationAuthenticationModule which is WSFederationAuthenticationModule.

ERROR:
The type 'WSFederationAuthenticationModule' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

```
    using System;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel;
    using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
    using Microsoft.SharePoint;
    using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
    using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;
    using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
    using CACAuthentication.Classes;
    using Microsoft.IdentityModel;

    private void EstablishSessionWithToken(SecurityToken securityToken)
                {

                    if (null == securityToken)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentNullException("securityToken");
                    }

                    SPFederationAuthenticationModule fam = SPFederationAuthenticationModule.Current;
                    if (fam == null) //**************ERRROR HERE ON fam*******************//
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException(null, "FederationAuthenticationModule");
                    }

                    fam.SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken(securityToken, SPSessionTokenWriteType.WriteSessionCookie);


                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was writing this I realized the problem after spending all day trying to figure it out. There isn't a local copy of the Microsoft.Identity.dll. I thought I had referenced it, but I had referenced the Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel and the System.IdentityModel. You have to install Microsoft.Identity via NuGet. Since I had already written the question I figured I would go ahead and post it so others can avoid this bonehead mistake.